# Why does webpack use script tag for dynamic import when dynamic "import()" is already supported?

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting, dynamic-import, esmodules

Lately I've been deep diving more about JS modules, Webpack, the difference between ES modules and CommonJS, and I came across the dynamic import topic. I was curious on how Webpack converts the dynamic `import()` statement and when I take a look at the generated bundled JS from webpack, turns out it loads the imported module by adding a `<script>` tag with `src` to it, and then removing it after the script has finished loading.

May I know why it is implemented this way? I thought we can use the `import()` statement right away as long as the entry script tag has the `type="module"`. Why does webpack need to convert it?

Comment: Because `import()` was not supported some time ago - and Webpack had to implement its functionality on its own by resolving the pathname locally on the filesystem while browsers resolve it over the URL.

Comment: But currently it is supported by major browsers so there's no need to transpile it. Is there a config in Webpack to disable the conversion?

Comment: If you are using `<script type="module">` are you sure you need webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the reasons of why as was already mentioned in a comment to your question, the simple solution to use native dynamic `import()` with webpack is to include a [magic comment](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) `/* webpackIgnore: true */` to all dynamic import statements:

```js
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ 'path-to-module.js')
```

If you would like to do this at build time to all dynamic import statements you can use [magic-comments-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/magic-comments-loader).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic imports in Webpack are performed by a [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/).
According to the [Github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/7644) there are 2 workarounds:

```js
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */"...")
```

or

```js
eval(`import('${moduleURL}')`).then(...)
```

Also, if you switch from Webpack to Vite (which uses ESbuild or SWC instead of Babel) - you should be able to utilize the native `import()` feature of the major browsers.